# Bounty disappeared

Tags: support, bounties

This question used to have a +50 bounty:
[ReportViewer Merge cells dynamically on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384436/reportviewer-merge-cells-dynamically-on-condition/7494448#7494448)

When I answered the question the bounty was still there. At the end of the bounty period, it said that there was a grace period of 24 hours. There was a countdown and when it got to 0, it reset to 24 hours. Now the bounty has disappeared.

Not that I cared that much about the bounty but I'm really curious about what happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [post revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7384436/revisions). It says:

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦

For you to have been awarded the bounty,

- the person who placed the bounty must manually award it to you **OR**
- your answer posted *after* the bounty was placed, must have a net score of +2 **OR**
- the question owner (who should've also placed the bounty) must have accepted your answer during the bounty period

None of these happened, so the bounty was was not awarded to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7384436/revisions

and

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Do you actually have to type that URL into your browser? I don't see an Edit History link on the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Waste no more time.](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an)