# Bounty not applied to accepted answer but question owner did not post the bounty

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

The [Bounty disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107139/bounty-disappeared) post sort of addresses my question but not completely. [Open Source Linux Acrobat Javascript Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079165/open-source-linux-acrobat-javascript-editor) had a bounty assigned to it, not by the question owner, but by another user which can be [seen here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hNcQcL_JLesJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/9079165/open-source-linux-acrobat-javascript-editor%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). My answer was posted and accepted after the bounty was initiated. However, the bounty was not applied [as seen in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9079165/revisions).

**Does the bounty owner, not the question owner, have to specifically award the bounty in this situation regardless of accepted answers and/or number of votes?**

The always a chance I missed something in the bounty rules. If that's the case, I apologize.

[Bounty not credited to accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109490/bounty-not-credited-to-accepted-answer) - similar question but still doesn't address my question.

Comment: You seem to think things are different when the question owner would have started the bounty? Then you missed a lot [in the bounty rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: You are correct, sir. My apologies: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) page (note that I have only taken some portions of it) -

> It is your responsibility to award the bounty during the seven-day period or the 24-hour grace period that follows it. You will receive several e-mail and site notifications as the bounty period draws to a close.
>
> You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it.
>   You can award a bounty on an answer without accepting it.
>
> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Comment: And "Bounty awards are no longer tied to accepted answer in any way." from http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: @JSuar: Yes, I think this covers that too - *You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it. You can award a bounty on an answer without accepting it.*